# Docusign Compoite Templates multiple server templates

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to render two templates together using the `compositeTemplates` attribute. However only the second one gets included. I believe this structure is correct because I can get one or the other if I just comment one out. According to the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____39) all I should need to set is the sequence. How can I get both server templates to be included in one envelope?

```
'emailSubject': "test doc",
'emailBurb': 'this is a test doc',
'status': 'sent',
'compositeTemplates': [{
    'serverTemplates': [
        # LT
        {
            'sequence': '1',
            'templateId': '9FA06158-4789-4473-B435-F81BF2C7D1D0',
        },
    ],
    'serverTemplates': [
    # ST 
        {
            'sequence': '2',
            'templateId': '235E5E2C-D4F1-4043-AE7E-793DD89268F3',
        },
    ],
    'inlineTemplates': [{
        'sequence': '1',
        'recipients': {
            'signers': [{
                'email': send_to,
                'name': "Tester",
                'recipientId': '1',
                'roleName': 'Signer',
                    'tabs': {
                    'textTabs': [
                        {
                            'tabLabel': 'full_address',
                            'value': 'Massachusetts'
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }],
        },
    }],
    'inlineTemplates': [{
        'sequence': '2',
        'recipients': {
            'signers': [{
                'email': send_to,
                'name': "Tester",
                'recipientId': '1',
                'roleName': 'Signer',
                    'tabs': {
                    'textTabs': [
                        {
                            'tabLabel': 'full_address',
                            'value': 'Massachusetts'
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }],
        },
    }],


}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you have there is actually combining the two server-templates.  The sequence in this case determines which documents/recipients take priority.  To included them both as a separate documents, you'd want something more like the below.  This has two composite templates.  Each one combines a server-side template with an in-line template.  I haven't tested this, but it should get you going.

```
'emailSubject': "test doc",
'emailBurb': 'this is a test doc',
'status': 'sent',
'compositeTemplates': [{
    'serverTemplates': [
        # LT
        {
            'sequence': '1',
            'templateId': '9FA06158-4789-4473-B435-F81BF2C7D1D0',
        },
    ],
    'inlineTemplates': [{
        'sequence': '2',
        'recipients': {
            'signers': [{
                'email': send_to,
                'name': "Tester",
                'recipientId': '1',
                'roleName': 'Signer',
                    'tabs': {
                    'textTabs': [
                        {
                            'tabLabel': 'full_address',
                            'value': 'Massachusetts'
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }],
        },
    }]
},
{
    'serverTemplates': [
    # ST 
        {
            'sequence': '1',
            'templateId': '235E5E2C-D4F1-4043-AE7E-793DD89268F3',
        },
    ],
    'inlineTemplates': [{
        'sequence': '2',
        'recipients': {
            'signers': [{
                'email': send_to,
                'name': "Tester",
                'recipientId': '1',
                'roleName': 'Signer',
                    'tabs': {
                    'textTabs': [
                        {
                            'tabLabel': 'full_address',
                            'value': 'Massachusetts'
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }],
        },
    }],
}]
```

Comment: thanks, I'm still having some issues implementing this solution. So the `compositeTemplates` array should have two `serverTemplates` keys (as well as 2 `inlineTemplates` keys)? Does sequence matter? I tried setting the first `serverTemplates` objects sequences both to 1 and the second both to 2.

Comment: No - the example I posted above has two compositeTemplate objects.  Each one has a single serverTemplates key and a single inlineTemplates key.